# Do I still need to synchronize static methods in this class?

Tags: java, synchronize

```
class Writer{
    static int a;
    static int b;

   public static void write(String inFile, String outFile){
        ...
   }
}
```

Now I use this class this way:

```
 Writer.write(f1, f2)
```

This line of code will be accessed by multiple threads. I feel I still need to protect the 'write()' method with the keyword "synchronized". But my question is, since Writer class only has static variables and static methods, the client code doesn't need to create any instance out of it. Do I still need to synchronize the write method?

Comment: Don't use the class this way. If the class has state, make the state per-instance.

Comment: What do you mean by "the class has state"?

Comment: It depends on the implementation. Does the `write` method modify `a` and `b`?

Comment: Of course, it does. In the method, it computes the value of a and b.

Comment: If you do synchronize it, make sure to give it a specific monitor and not leave out the monitor statement, so as to avoid using the class itself as the default monitor.

Comment: I believe that `static` has ***nothing*** to do with whether or not the method should be synchronized (it should), but may have some bearing on *how* you synchronize.